# Aligning multiple objects with the same spacing to eachother, vertically

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment

:)

I did create something like a roadmap with a checklist below each subject. However, after the 7th checkpoint the auto snapping didn't work anymore and now I struggle to align them properly. They contain a square (check box) a icon (text / fontawesome) and a text description and are in folders.

I tried to select all folders and use the alignment tool but they either collapse into each other and build one huge chunk or they space each other out.

I did a little research but could only find scripts regarding the centering of objects on the canvas.

Help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Straight forward:

1. Select all the layers you want to distribute, click on the first then shift click on the last if they are adjacent. Otherwise, use the Ctrl-Click on at a time to select them
2. From the menu, choose Layer/Distribute/Bottom edges
3. They will be equally spaced between the first and the last

Of course, if you do not have enough space to accommodate all, they will bunch up. I that case you will need to adjust their sizes. While you have them all selected, you can optionally align them to the left, center, or right from the Layer/Align options. If you like to align them at the center of the background, include that in your selected layers. Background will remain stationary and everything else will align with respect to that.

Here are some screen captures to show the before, adjustment, after:

[image]

[image]

[image]